# document.getElementById("myRewardsHistorydivXML").innerHTML rearraging closing tags

Tags: html, dom, fusioncharts

Inside a div ,place xml data for fusion chart(StackedChart3D), while getting innerHtml of div self terminated category tag are getting close in wrong order ..below is code snipshot..I am not sure what is going wrong in gatting data from DOM
Graph Data

```
<div id="myRewardsHistorydivXML">
    <graph bgColor='F1f1f1' caption='' subcaption='' xaxisname='' yaxisname=''  canvasbgcolor='F1F1F1' numdivlines='0' showLegend='1' yAxisMaxValue='50'> 
    **<categories font='Arial' fontSize='10' fontColor='000000'> 
    <category name='2011' /> 
    <category name='2012' /> 
    </categories>**
    <dataset seriesname='My Life' color='1941A5' showValues='0' alpha='100'>
        <set value='25675' color='1941A5'></set>
        <set value='22475' color='1941A5'></set>
    </dataset>
    <dataset seriesname='My Health' color='FF0000' showValues='0' alpha='100'>
        <set value='21675' color='1941A5'></set>
        <set value='23531' color='1941A5'></set>
    </dataset>
   <graph>
</div>
```

in Watch Window of Browser while checking innerHTML of element document.getElementById("myRewardsHistorydivXML").innerHTML ..Its apperaing

```
<graph bgColor='F1f1f1' caption='' subcaption='' xaxisname='' yaxisname='' canvasbgcolor='F1F1F1' numdivlines='0' showLegend='1' yAxisMaxValue='50'> 
     <categories font='Arial' fontSize='10' fontColor='000000'> 
     **<category name='2011'> 
     <category name='2012'>
     </category></category>**
    </categories>
<dataset seriesname='My Life' color='1941A5' showValues='0' alpha='100'>
  <set value='25675' color='1941A5'></set>
  <set value='22475' color='1941A5'></set>
</dataset>
<dataset seriesname='My Health' color='FF0000' showValues='0' alpha='100'>
  <set value='21675' color='1941A5'></set>`enter code here`
  <set value='23531' color='1941A5'></set>
</dataset>
<graph>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dumping XML into an HTML document and the browser is trying to parse it as HTML.

`<category name='2011' />` is treated as a start tag for an unrecognised element, not as a self-closing tag.

The end tags are not being rearranged, they are missing and the browser is inserting them at where it thinks the right place is to keep the DOM valid.

Comment: This code was already in use since April 2012 and no problem was faced ..now this has come as Production issue